# How to Wrap Text Within an Image-Link? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have some code which displays images from imgur.
When hovering over an image, I want the title attribute to appear at the top of the image.

I have achieved all of this, but when the text becomes visible, it only appears on one line and writes over itself when it runs out of space, as in the image.[image: Image of the overlapping text]

I would like the text to start on a new line once it reaches the end of it's container.

I have tried adding word-wrap: break-word; to each of the CSS selector below, as well as to a P selector (as the link is wrapped in a p-tag).

Any advice on how to resolve this is much appreciated!

I have the following html:

```
<section id='photos'>
  <p> 
     <a class='hovertext' href='http://i.imgur.com/gallery/eWlGSdR.jpg'      title='Opened my window shade while flying over Japan, noticed a volcano was erupting. (OC) [2448x2448]'> 
           <img src='http://i.imgur.com/eWlGSdR.jpg' alt=''> 
   </a>
</p>
```

And the following CSS:

```
 a.hovertext {
   position: relative;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   text-align: left;
 }

 a.hovertext:before {
   content: attr(title);
   position: absolute;
   top: -1;
   padding: 0.5em 20px;
   width: 90%;
   text-decoration: none !important;
   color: red;
   opacity: 0.0;
 }

a.hovertext:hover:before, a.hovertext:focus:before {
   opacity: 1.0;
 }
```

Comment: I tried using your HTML & CSS code in JSFiddle and it is working just as you expect it to. http://jsfiddle.net/5h49mers/1/

Comment: same here. what browser are you using?

Comment: Dinesh you are a legend

I have been on a mad goose chase - you gave me the clue I needed.
Further up the page, my #photos section had a line which read 'line-height: 0;'

Removed this and  it now works fine- thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dinesh said in the comments, this was caused by poor code awareness, as elsewhere in the code, I was calling 'line-height:0;' on the #photos element.

Removing this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you coul use some java script on this, if you only want to make it add a extra line to it, correct me if im wrong.

Here's an example what i think you mean:
    First add this text next your class="hovertext" :
    id="HoverText"

```
Add this part after your body or paste the code between script into a .js file and call it with
<script src="filename.js"></script>

<script>
HoverText=document.getElementById("HoverText");
HoverText.onclick=function(){ClickToShowText()};
function ClickToShowText(){
HoverText.innerHTML+="<br>New line with text";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the break tag at the end of the text that's supposed to be on the first line.

```
</br>
```

easy